# Meteor.user() Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null

Tags: javascript, meteor

Im working with the Meteor framework and came by this error when I tried to return the name of the current user to a template helper.

```
Template.user.userName = function (){
    return Meteor.user().name;

}

<template name ="user">
    {{userName}}
</template>
```

I keep getting this error: (Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null)

However everything works fine from the javascript console.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is Meteor.user()? Have you inspected it to see its value (likely null)?

Comment: It's a javascript object provided by Meteor. It returns [object Object] without the .name property.

Comment: console.log returns two lines, null and then the object one right after the other.  The object contains all the expected properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Meteor.user()` returns null if there is no user logged in. So to be safe you should do something like `Meteor.user() ? Meteor.user().name : ''`.