# How can I prevent Meteor.user()'s timing hole?

Tags: javascript, meteor

A template requests...

```
if (this.userRequesting._id === Meteor.user()._id) { ... }
```

...to check for a person's identity. (I suspect this isn't the best way to handle this, but I'll save that for another question so as to not overload this question).

My issue is that this results in a tremendous error cascade suggesting that `Meteor.user()` is undefined, *only* on pageload... Once the page is loaded, this code executes without a problem. Clearly, there is a timing hole (or so I believe) where `Meteor.user()` remains unassigned for a split second on page load. Replacing the above code with...

```
    ____________
if (Meteor.user() && this.userRequesting._id == Meteor.user()._id) { ... }
```

...fixes the problem, but... Come *on*... That can't possibly be kosher. What assumption am I erroneously making about templating and Meteor?

If relevant, I'm using `accounts-password` as my cheat-y accounts manager.

---

**[Edit]:** This looks like the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087820/meteor-user-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-name-of-null), but I'm leaving this question up on the premise that I'm looking for a fix, not a workaround. (I already know checking for `Meteor.user()` resolves this.)

Comment: What you did is a fix not a workaround. You must understand reactive contexts and subscription loading.

Comment: That's just how you do it. `Meteor.user()` can be null, so you need to check it first. Until elvis operator `?.` finds its way to Javascript, there's no escape from such constructs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you've basically gotten it right. When you first refresh the page, the user isn't consider to be logged in, and it has to verify that it is. But the template stuff is called immediately, and then again when other stuff is loaded (if you put an `alert` in a `rendered` method, you'll notice that). The best solution is exactly what you suggested, although you can use `Meteor.userId()` to get just the id:

```
if (Meteor.userId() && Meteor.userId() === this.userRequesting._id) {
    // ...
```

Comment: Sounds good, though it's a little disappointing Meteor doesn't have a way of dealing with this.

Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Meteor.userId()` to get the `_id` attribute of the signed in user or `null` (I think) if the user is not signed in.