# Meteor.user().profile returns 'profile' undefined

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a helper called 'isActive' and a template named 'create'.. see below

```
Template.create.isActive = function () {
  return Meteor.user().profile.isActive;
};
```

When I try to run this code it returns the following in console: "Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile' of undefined".

Basically I want to pull the 'isActive' info from the current user profile and return it to the template. Any idea why this does not work?

### Update

```
//startup on server side:
Meteor.publish("userData", function() {
  if (this.userId) {
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId},
      {fields: {'profile.isActive': 1}});
  } else {
    this.ready();
  }
});

//startup on client side
Meteor.subscribe('userData');

//router
this.route('list', {
  path: 'list',
  waitOn : function () {
    return Meteor.subscribe('userData');
  },
  data : function () {
    return Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
  },
  action : function () {
    if (this.ready()) {
      this.render();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Isn't the error message _TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile' of `null`_?

Comment: Yes it is.. isActive is a property within the profile object.

Comment: Then you should should change `undefined` to `null` in your question. These aren't the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Meteor.user() is undefined. You are either not logged in with any user or your template is rendered before the users collection is synced to the client. If you use a router like iron router you can wait for the collection being available or for the user being logged on.

Without using a router the easiest would be to check if the user is defined:

```
Template.create.isActive = function () {
    return Meteor.user() && Meteor.user().profile.isActive;
}
```

Since Meteor.user() is reactive the template will be rerendered when the user changes, i.e. when it is available.

This is a common error btw, see also:

- [Meteor.user() Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087820/meteor-user-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-name-of-null)
- [How can I prevent Meteor.user()'s timing hole?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478279/how-can-i-prevent-meteor-users-timing-hole?lq=1)

Comment: Is `profile` always defined on `Meteor.user()` or should you test that too?

Comment: profile is always created for each user and is defined as long as you are not changing the publish function for the users (e.g. to hide user data from being available on every client).

Comment: Thanks Florian. This eliminates the problem for looking up there profile info.. however, it creates a new problem. For one reason or another this deactivates my validation checking (I use a bootstrap validator, submitHandler) and when I click the submit button to insert information into my collection the page refreshes and no information is inserted into the database.. on startup I publish and subscribe to my user data and then in my router I waitOn the subscription... this seems convoluted though; is this the best way to do this?

Comment: I also just discovered that I need to refresh the screen once for the profile info to be read.. any idea why that is?